# One Web Server Two NIC with Two Different Wan Network

Tags: networking, nic, wide-area-network

I got one Web Server (IIS), MS windows server 2012 with two nic and want to connect this two nic to different ISP with different public ips address. I got totally seperate set of infrastructure of this two different wan network.

For eg.

Nic 1 is with 192.168.168.110 Subnet 255.255.255.0 and default Gateway 192.168.168.168 with public ip address 113.xx.xx.xxx and web site name **us.example.com**

Nic 2 is with 192.168.0.160 Subnet 255.255.255.0 and default Gateway 192.168.0.1 with public ip address 203.xx.xx.xxx and web site name **uk.example.com**

The purpose of using two different wan as redudancy and also latency issue for different region.

Is their any issue or anything i should take note for this setup? How the server know which NIC they should use when they browsing. As i research i need to remove one of the NIC's Default gateway to let the another one to be the main for browsing.

Will removing one of the NIC's default gateway will have any effect to its capability of accesssing from outside?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "I need to remove one of the NIC's default gateways to let the other one be the main for browsing?" Are you saying that with your current setup you can only access one of the sites at a time?

Comment: @D34DM347 I still in the planning to setup, if i didnt remain both NIC default gateway, will this causing any issue? like for example when i use the web server to browse?

Comment: Don't browse on your web server.

Answer (score 2):

Windows, and most OSes only "use" one default gateway at a time. It doesn't distinguish on a per NIC basis. If you have two default gateways in your routing table on the server (the default gateway in the NIC screen becomes a default route (0.0.0.0) in the routing table) then the one with the lowest metric will be used. You can use 'route print' to see that the two 0.0.0.0 entries have different metrics.

So, if you remove the default gateway from one of the NICs that has incoming traffic, then that traffic will be sent back out of the default gateway in the routing table (the default gateway on the other NIC) and dropped on the other side ( as unsolicited traffic ). This happens because there are no routes to the destination of the incoming traffic! You *could* set up local routing to send specific traffic to required interface, but you'd need to know the specific network ranges you wanted to deal with.

If you need redundancy for two ISPs, then you should have that redundancy set up on an actual router, or a switch that can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway is for the public Internet access, that means for all the other networks not belonging to these two /24 networks you have mentioned. Concerning the web server probably you will have to create a port mapping and your local ip address will be NATted to a public one. So your traffic internally will take place with the local subnet so default gateway has nothing to do, you can dismiss it and not add gateway at all, this is only need it for the outgoing traffic from server to the public, Internet.