# Isolating IIS to one NIC

Tags: networking, nic, windows-server-2019

asking if its even possible and how to do it:
I have a fresh server (Windows Server 2019 Essentials) with two NICs. I have two separated internet access providers (two ADSL modems).

Is it possible, to use one NIC to connect server to my router, which defines my network (192.168.1.*), all other computers are connected to this network and SECOND NIC to connect directly to second modem (without router in between) and define, that only IIS can communicate with this NIC and on this IP?

Why? I have one static and one dynamic IP. Static is for IIS, while dynamic offers a tiny bit more security, thus using it for my network.

Problems so far? I get constant warning, that I have set up two different gateways (one is router gateway, second is gateway from ISP) on this system and this can cause serious troubles..

I have seen [One Web Server Two NIC with Two Different Wan Network](https://serverfault.com/questions/721659/one-web-server-two-nic-with-two-different-wan-network) but I got confused reading that. Not sure if user managed to do what he intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should not multihome the server. The best methid to accomplish your scenario would be a good router that manage both Internet connection.

Get a sophos UTM maybe or pfsense.

In the router after you make rules that by default your IIS use the good ISP, and you set your LAN to use the second ISP.

That way you will be protected from internet traffic too, as your IIS would not be directly on the internet.

Comment: Yes, getting additional router with two "WAN ports" could solve a problem, but that adds another layer of configuration to whole network.. Not to mention that kind of routers are not cheap, ha? I'll search in this direction too, didnt gave up on my idea tho..Thank you for your reply..

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is suppress the warning you have to delete one of the gateways (the router one most likely) and you can access it from the other Lan easily since it has static ip.
However, if you do want to stop traffic to your IIS from the other network then you can try this [steps](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003545394-How-to-allow-restrict-connections-from-an-IP-address-to-a-website-in-IIS-on-Windows-Server)

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to explain: its not about blocking IPs on my IIS, its the other way around: I want IIS to only communicate (ingress, outgress) on one NIC, regardless of IPs. I'm searching for setting where you can select which NIC can application use (in my scenario IIS) for anything network related..